# GWT activity mayStop and Hyperlink issue

Tags: gwt, android-activity

I have an activity with a mayStop() method. I am having two issues with it that pertain to a hyperlink on the page.

The first issue is that if I hit refresh or the window's X I get a dialog box that wraps my mayStop() text with "Are you sure you want to navigate away from this page?" and "Press OK to continue, or Cancel to stay on the current page." That is fine.
When I hit the hyperlink, I only see my mayStop() text without the wrapping text. Why is that?

The second issue is that if I hit Cancel in response to the hyperlink click, hitting the link again results in not getting the mayStop() challenge at all. It is as if I am not hitting the hyperlink.

Has anyone run into these issues?
Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Doug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference in "behavior" is that the first dialog box is the one from the browser when you try to prevent the user from navigating away, while the other is `PlaceController` calling `Window.confirm()`. Each browser uses a different dialog box for the first case, so there's no way to mimic it for everyone, and it's probably not a good thing either (navigating away from the app vs. navigating within the app).

As for your second issue, the events are generated by the browser "history" changing; if you prevent navigating away (from the Place), the URL stays the same (there's noway to know what to do to "rollback" the change: `History.back()`, `History.next()`, `History.newItem()` but then you destroy the existing "next" history ?), so when you click again on the link, you don't make the URL change, and no event is fired.

It's expected that you use `PlaceController.goTo` to navigate when you use places, not `Hyperlink` or `History`.